# how do I get my filter buttons to work in React using a json file?

Tags: reactjs, json, filter

Ive recently moved my product information from my shop to a separate JSON file and I cant work out how to fix my filter buttons as the information is on longer in the same page. My products are appearing on the page so the information is being read from the JSON file as its imported into my App. Any ideas would be much Appreciated. Below is my shop file and product Json file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AddToCart from './Components/AddToCart';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate  }
from "react-router-dom";
import Product from './Product';

const HOME_GARDEN = 'home and garden';
const ART = 'Art';
const ACCESSORIES = 'Accessories';
const DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS = 'Digital Photographs';
const FASHION = 'Fashion';
const FOOTWEAR = 'Footwear';
const JEWELLERY = 'Jewellery';
const ALL = 'All';

export default function Shop({ products, setCart, cart, handleClick }) {


const navigate = useNavigate()

const [category, setCategory] = useState(ALL);

const getProductsInCategory = () => {
if (category === ALL) {
    return products;
} else {
    return products.filter((product) => product.category === category);
}
};

 return (
  <>
  <h1>Shop</h1>

    <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ART)}>
      Art</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(HOME_GARDEN)}>
        Home and Garden</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ACCESSORIES)}>
      Accessories</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS)}>
      Digital Photographs</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(FASHION)}>
      Fashion</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(FOOTWEAR)}>
      Footwear</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(JEWELLERY)}> Jewellery</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ALL)}>
          All</button>

  <div className="products">
      {getProductsInCategory().map((product, idx) =>(
        <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4>£{product.cost}</h4>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <br />



          <AddToCart product={product} cart={cart} setCart={setCart}/>

          <Link to={`/Product/${product.id}`}><button type="button">Product</button> 
       </Link>

        </div>
    ))}
   </div>

   </>
   );
   }
```

and my JSON file with all my product info

```
{
"productsData" :
[
{
  "id": "0001",
  "category": "ART",
  "name": "Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork",
  "cost": 200,
  "image":"images/bowiebig.jpeg",
  "image2": "images/bowiesmall.jpeg",
  "image3":"images/bowie2small.jpeg",
  "description": "Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork floral 
  painting on wooden canvas with an original pop art style David Bowie Mugshot on top 
  painting is framed with a red baroque style frame including the words deadly 
  flowers bloom around frame"

   },
   {   "id": "0002",
    "category": "ACCESSORIES",
    "name": "F&F Ladies Long Black Real Leather Size Small Gloves",
    "cost": 35,
    "image":"images/Fred.jpeg",
    "image2": "",
    "image3":"",
    "description": "F&F Ladies Long Black Real Leather Size Small Gloves with ruched 
     horizontal detailing on the front. Gloves are in good condition "

    },
    {
      "id": "0003",
      "category": "DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS",
      "name": "Black on Black Original Limited Edition Digital Photograph",
      "cost": 50,
      "image":"images/BlackonBlack.jpg",
      "image2": "",
      "image3":"",
      "description": "Upon purchase you will receive links to download the digital 
       photograph in the thank you page of the checkout as well as an emailed link 
       that will last 30 days. "

      },

      {
        "id": "0004",
        "category": "FASHION",
        "name": "Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim Skirt",
        "cost": 50,
        "image":"images/Boy.jpeg",
        "image2": "",
        "image3":"",
        "description": "Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim 
         Skirt. BOY London sizes run small. This skirt is size 8/10 even though the 
         label says large. Condition is New with tags."

      },

      {   "id": "0005",
          "category": "FOOTWEAR",
          "name": "Ladies Size 8 / 41 Black Real Suede Jeffrey Campbell Platform Open 
           Toe Sandals",
          "cost": 60,
          "image":"images/Campbell.jpeg",
          "image2": "",
          "image3":"",
          "description": "Ladies UK Size 8 European size 41 black real suede Jeffrey 
           Campbell high platform open-toe sandals with adjustable strap. The sandals 
           are in good condition as theyve only worn outside a few times. The heel 
           and platform is made from wood so the sandals are sturdy but relatively 
           lightweight. "

        },
        {
           "id": "0005",
            "category": "JEWELLERY",
            "name": "Jean Paul Gaultier Scandal Bottle Top Customised Fishnet 
             Necklace",
            "cost": 50,
            "image":"images/Scandal.jpeg",
            "image2": "",
            "image3":"",
            "description": "Jean Paul Gaultier Scandal Bottle Top Customised Necklace 
             made with braided fishnets."

          }

      ]}
```

Comment: Do you pass the `products` prop?

Comment: how would I do that? thanks

Comment: @LuminousButter you should return or filter on products.productsData rather than products because your json file contains a object productsData which is an array.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help when I try that is says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: @LuminousButter When you render your `Shop` component, you need to pass all the required props to it. You can do it like this:
`<Shop products={products.productsData} setCart={yourSetCartFunc} cart={yourCart} handleClick={yourClickHandlerFunc} />`.

Comment: Thanks Ive tried that but its still not working